# Is there anything wrong with coloring in a white spot on an esrog?

Tags: halacha, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, color

The Shaarei Teshuva seems to permit dying a semi dried out lulav. Why don't we find people doing such a thing to a white spot on an esrog?

[https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.645.6?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.645.6?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

Comment: I've never heard of anyone dyeing a lulav either fwiw

Comment: Me neither, but the Shaarei Teshuva does sanction it...

Comment: That's fine but why be surprised that you don't see people painting etrugim if it doesn't seem like we paskin like that opinion even for lulav. In other words I'd think you'd first ask about lulav before being surprised about etrog